# Using Delphi's message keyword handler syntax with variable constants?

Tags: delphi

### Short Version

Any way to use:

```
    procedure WMStuff(var Message: TMessage); message WM_Stuff;
```

when `WM_Stuff` is a variable?

### Long version

Delphi has an absolutely lovely bit of compiler magic to make handling messages so easy. You simply tag your procedure with the `message WM_TheMessage` keyword:

```
procedure WMGrobFrobber(var Message: TMessage); message WM_GrobFrobber;
```

and your procedure will be called to handle that message. No subclassing. No replacing, storing, and calling base window procedures. Just easy simple magic.

### For constants

The message works great when the `WM_GrobFrobber` is a `const`:

```
const
   WM_GrobFrobber = WM_APP + $12A9;  //hopefully nobody's used this message before
```

But the downside of a constant declared like that is:

- i have to hope no other component or library has already used that constant for something else when the message gets broadcast to all windows
- i cannot broadcast, send, or post that message to other processes

Windows recommends you use **[RegisterWindowMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagew)** to ensure you safely have a unique message number:

> Defines a new window message that is guaranteed to be unique throughout the system. The message value can be used when sending or posting messages.
>
> The **RegisterWindowMessage** function is typically used to register messages for communicating between two cooperating applications.
>
> If two different applications register the same message string, the applications return the same message value. The message remains registered until the session ends.
>
> Only use **RegisterWindowMessage** when more than one application must process the same message. For sending private messages within a window class, an application can use any integer in the range [WM_USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644931(v=VS.85).aspx) through 0x7FFF. (Messages in this range are private to a window class, not to an application. For example, predefined control classes such as **BUTTON**, **EDIT**, **LISTBOX**, and **COMBOBOX** may use values in this range.)

And that is what i need:

- i will be sending (or receiving) messages from other window classes (e.g. `TForm1` vs `TForm2` vs `TVirtualTreeHintWorkerThread`)
- i will be sending (or receiving) messages from other windows classes in other applications.

So i register my message:

```
var
   WM_GrobFrobber: Cardinal;

initialization
    WM_GrobFrobber := RegisterWindowMessage('Contoso.Grobber.GrobFrobber message');
```

### The constant variable

But now i can no longer use the nice syntax:

```
procedure WMGrobFrobber(var Message: TMessage); message WM_GrobFrobber;
   //Constant expression expected
```

:(

I tried hacking an *assignable type constant*:

```
{$J+}
const
   WM_GrobFrobber: Cardinal = 0;

initialization
    WM_GrobFrobber := RegisterWindowMessage('Contoso.Grobber.GrobFrobber message');
```

But the `message` keyword does not accept *pseudo-*constants either:

```
procedure WMGrobFrobber(var Message: TMessage); message WM_GrobFrobber;
   //Constant expression expected
```

Is there any way to salvage the lovely, easy `message` syntax, and not have to subclass every window that might want to handle a message?

Especially since the message really **isn't** a constant; but is invented and registered by people who are **not** me.

Comment: This is not a matter of syntax, a message method is installed in the DMT with its message ID. The ID is how the handler is found at run time.

Comment: As such, you can only [hack](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2007/03/hack15-overriding-message-and-dynamic.html) your way.

Comment: The value must be known at compile time, so the compiler can construct the dynamic method table. Therefore it can not be a message value determined at runtime. You can hack this, but that is an **extremely** ugly hack.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Man, that is one *ugly* hack; I'd rather go without message handling!

Comment: You can always handle your registered message in the method for handling unhandled messages  (forgot the name, probably something like WndProc).

Comment: If you can add a message method, then you need to derive a sub class. Which is no different from overriding `WndProc`. In fact if you want to change behaviour you don't need to derive a sub class at all. You can use the `WindowProc` property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message ID associated with a [message method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Message_Methods) must be a [constant expression](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions).

Answer (score 11):

As David states in his answer, message ID's in declarative message handlers are required to be constant expressions, so there is no way to implement a handler for a variable message number in this way.

However, you still do not need to sub-class every window to be able to respond to such messages.  Or rather, you do not need to perform any *further* sub-classing than you are already doing by declaring a form or control class.

You can handle your custom, registered message by over-riding the virtual `WndProc` method.  You won't be able to use a `select .. case` statement to handle the message since this similarly requires constant expressions for the matching cases, but you can use a simple `if .. then` statement to catch your message, calling `inherited` for everything else:

```
procedure TMyForm.WndProc(var aMessage: TMessage);
begin
  if aMessage.Msg = WM_GrobFrobber then
  begin
    { Handle the message or pass to a WMGrobFrabber() method 
      with suitably repacked and typed params, as required/desired }
  end
  else
    inherited WndProc(aMessage);
end;
```

You could introduce a `virtual` `WMGrobFrabber` in a form class which you then use consistently as the base class for all forms in your application(s), so that you can simply override that method to handle this message, rather than having to regurgitate the `WndProc` conditional handler code every time.

This doesn't solve all your problems.  It doesn't provide a way to use the declarative message handler syntax, but it is still quite elegant (imho).

If such messages are used exclusively for responding to broadcast messages (which I believe is the only circumstance in which you need be concerned about message id's conflicting with those used by others) then you could create a non-visual component that implements a message handler specifically to respond to this message by firing an event with a published event handler.  Then you don't need to sub-class at all to implement a response to such broadcasts on a form, just drop a handler component on the form and implement a handler for the component's event.

That is obviously more complicated than would be appropriate to deal with in an answer to this question, but might be worth considering.

Comment: You don't even need to override the class. You can replace the `WindowProc` property.

Comment: Of course overriding `WndProc` is the much easier route. If you replace the `.WindowProc` you have to a) store the old WindowProc, b) call the old WindowProc, c) restore the old WindowProc before the class is destroyed; a real mess.

Comment: @Ian Remember though you that you were the one that didn't want to override WndProc.

Comment: I didn't want to replace the WindowProc with my own, store the old one, have to call the old one, have to not crash when removing my subclass in the wrong order, playing nice with someone else who may subclass me after me, etc. Overriding in place is much easier. Still, the easiest is the compiler magic one.

Comment: @Ian I guess my point is that overriding WndProc requires that you derive a new class, which I thought you wanted to avoid. Adding message methods also requires deriving a new class. Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by "not have to subclass every window that might want to handle a message".

Answer (score 0):

If you save this code to HeartWare.VCL.Extensions.MultiCastMessage.PAS

```
UNIT HeartWare.VCL.Extensions.MultiCastMessage;

INTERFACE

USES WinAPI.Messages,
     VCL.Forms,
     Generics.Collections;

TYPE
  TForm         = CLASS(VCL.Forms.TForm)
                    DESTRUCTOR  Destroy; OVERRIDE;
                  STRICT PRIVATE
                    TYPE        TMessageNo       = Cardinal;
                    TYPE        TMessageHandler  = REFERENCE TO PROCEDURE(VAR MSG : TMessage);
                    TYPE        TMessageHandlers = TList<TMessageHandler>;
                    TYPE        TEvents          = TObjectDictionary<TMessageNo,TMessageHandlers>;
                    VAR         Events           : TEvents;
                  STRICT PROTECTED
                    TYPE        TToken           = RECORD
                                                     MsgNo,Index        : Cardinal
                                                   END;
                  PROTECTED
                    PROCEDURE   WndProc(VAR Message : TMessage); OVERRIDE;
                    FUNCTION    AddHandler(MsgNo : TMessageNo ; Handler : TMessageHandler) : TToken;
                    PROCEDURE   RemoveHandler(VAR Token : TToken);
                  END;

IMPLEMENTATION

USES System.SysUtils;

FUNCTION TForm.AddHandler(MsgNo : TMessageNo ; Handler : TMessageHandler) : TToken;
  VAR
    Handlers    : TMessageHandlers;

  BEGIN
    IF NOT Assigned(Events) THEN Events:=TEvents.Create([doOwnsValues]);
    IF NOT Events.TryGetValue(MsgNo,Handlers) THEN BEGIN
      Handlers:=TMessageHandlers.Create;
      Events.Add(MsgNo,Handlers)
    END;
    Result.MsgNo:=MsgNo;
    Result.Index:=Handlers.Add(Handler)
  END;

DESTRUCTOR TForm.Destroy;
  BEGIN
    FreeAndNIL(Events);
    INHERITED
  END;

PROCEDURE TForm.RemoveHandler(VAR Token : TToken);
  BEGIN
    Events[Token.MsgNo][Token.Index]:=NIL;
    Token:=Default(TToken)
  END;

PROCEDURE TForm.WndProc(VAR Message : TMessage);
  VAR
    Handlers    : TMessageHandlers;
    Handler     : TMessageHandler;

  BEGIN
    IF Assigned(Events) AND Events.TryGetValue(Message.Msg,Handlers) THEN
      FOR Handler IN Handlers DO IF Assigned(Handler) AND (Message.Result=0) THEN Handler(Message);
    IF Message.Result=0 THEN INHERITED
  END;


END.
```

and include this unit as the last one in the form that you want to be able to either handle multiple handlers for a message, or handle messages with a run-time dependant message number, then you can accomplish this easily.

Use it as follows:

Create a new VCL application and place three buttons on the form, named *RegisterBtn*, *UnregisterBtn* and *ExecBtn* with appropriate captions. Ensure that the "Enabled" property for *UnregisterBtn* and *ExecBtn* is set to "FALSE" in the property editor, and "TRUE" for the *RegisterBtn*. Create a message handler as follows in your form:

```
PROCEDURE TForm1.Handler(VAR MSG : TMessage);
  BEGIN
    ShowMessage('Handler!')
  END;
```

and add the following variable definition to your form as well:

```
Token : TForm.TToken;
```

(ie.

```
private
  { Private declarations }
  Token       : TForm.TToken;
  PROCEDURE   Handler(VAR MSG : TMessage);
```

)

Then create click handlers for all three and fill them out as follows:

```
PROCEDURE TForm1.RegisterBtnClick(Sender : TObject);
  BEGIN
    RegisterBtn.Enabled:=FALSE;
    UnregisterBtn.Enabled:=TRUE;
    ExecBtn.Enabled:=TRUE;
    Token:=AddHandler(RegisterWindowMessage('Ohhh'),Handler);
    ShowMessage('MessageNo: '+IntToHex(Token.MsgNo,4))
  END;

PROCEDURE TForm1.UnregisterBtnClick(Sender : TObject);
  BEGIN
    RemoveHandler(Token);
    ExecBtn.Enabled:=FALSE;
    UnregisterBtn.Enabled:=FALSE;
    RegisterBtn.Enabled:=TRUE
  END;

PROCEDURE TForm1.ExecBtnClick(Sender : TObject);
  BEGIN
    PostMessage(Handle,Token.MsgNo,0,0)
  END;
```

Run it, and click the "Register", "Unregister" and "Exec" button to try it out.